# Dataflow batch insert to BigQuery not able to find dataset in asia-northeast1 region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

We have a BigQuery dataset located in asia-northeast1 region. We are trying to run a dataflow job which reads events from pub/sub and writes into BigQuery through BigQueryIO FILE_LOADS method.

When we run the dataflow to insert into BigQuery dataset(located in US region) it works but when we run the dataflow to insert into BigQuery dataset(located in asia-northeast1) it gives us below error.

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to insert job: beam_load_starterpipelinechintan0sureliya0619062952b1babd6f_bc8eb81e4c0f48c5bc9fe8268596d9e5_2aa762b44d22c1bad4faa10e3e95f341_00001_00000-0, aborting after 9 .
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.startJob(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:232)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.startJob(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:203)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.startLoadJob(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:143)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.load(WriteTables.java:262)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.access$600(WriteTables.java:79)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.processElement(WriteTables.java:157)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Not found: Dataset datapipelinedev:event",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "Not found: Dataset datapipelinedev:event"
}
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.startJob(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:217)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.startJob(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:203)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryServicesImpl$JobServiceImpl.startLoadJob(BigQueryServicesImpl.java:143)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.load(WriteTables.java:262)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables.access$600(WriteTables.java:79)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.processElement(WriteTables.java:157)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:138)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.startBundle(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:60)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.reallyStartBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:300)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.startBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:226)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.start(ParDoOperation.java:35)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1211)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:137)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:959)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We earlier tried to do streaming inserts in BigQuery located in asia-northeast1 region and it works but we need to load using batch jobs to avoid BigQuery streaming buffer.

We found below things while debugging

1. Dataflow is writing table rows in our GCS temporary
   location which is in asia-northeast1 region
2. Dataflow is fetching those temporary files and trying to insert into the destination tables but not able to do because it is not able to find BigQuery dataset

We tried to find out whether is there any possibility to set the BigQueryIO region for BigQueryIO.writeTableRows() but we did not find any.

Below is the piece of code which inserts into BigQuery using BigQueryIO dynamic destinations FILE_LOADS method.

```
windowed_items.apply("batch_insert_into_respective_table", new ReadEventJson_bigquery())
    .apply("Write_events_to_BQ",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(new DynamicDestinations<TableRow, String>() {
                public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> element) {
                    String destination = EventSchemaBuilder
                            .fetch_destination_based_on_event(element.getValue().get("event").toString());
                    return destination;
                }

                @Override
                public TableDestination getTable(String table) {
                    String destination = EventSchemaBuilder.fetch_table_name_based_on_event(table);
                    return new TableDestination(destination, destination);
                }

                @Override
                public TableSchema getSchema(String table) {
                    TableSchema table_schema = EventSchemaBuilder.fetch_table_schema_based_on_event(table);
                    return table_schema;
                }
            }).withMethod(Method.FILE_LOADS).withTriggeringFrequency(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
                    .withNumFileShards(1000).withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
    );
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189796/dataflow-cant-read-from-bigquery-dataset-in-region-asia-northeast1?noredirect=1#comment88851350_50189796. It's also not possible to read from a dataset in Tokyo.

Comment: Yes @GrahamPolley, We have gone through your question earlier. Any updates you got at your end?

Comment: I've raised a public issue tracker here mate: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110449363

Comment: Thanks for the tracker link @GrahamPolley

Comment: They have fixed this issue in Beam 2.5.0 SDK